# extend from class name in another file sass

Tags: css, sass, styling, bem

So I'm currently doing some styling, following the BEM standard.

An example of what I'm doing could be this:

```
.block{ 
  &__element {
  }
}
```

what i would like to do is this:

```
// file a 
.block {
 ...
}
```

-

```
// file b
// add magic to reference the `block`class in file a  
&__elelemnt {
 ...
}
```

What I'm currently doing:

```
// file a 
.block {
 ...
}
```

-

```
// file b
.block__elelemnt {
 ...
}
```

(manually adding the `block` part to the name)

Is there any way to reference this in a smarter way?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have this file structure:

```
block-1/
--block-1.scss
--element-1.scss
--element-2.scss
block-2/
--block-1.scss
--element-1.scss
--element-2.scss
```

And import elements files info block files.

**block.scss:**

```
.block {
    color: red;

    @import "element-1.scss";
    @import "element-2.scss";
}
```

**element-1.scss:**

```
&__element-1 {
    color: green;
}
```

Compiles to:

```
.block {
    color: red;

    &__element-1 {
        color: green;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is perhaps the best you can do.

```
$namespace: "block";

.#{$namespace}-myClass {
    ...
}
```

OUTPUT

```
.block-myClass {
    ...
}
```

You can keep a variable `$namespace` at the top of your file or in a different file and `import` it. The advantage of using a variable is you can update it once and all your references will be updated.

Answer (score 0):

SASS is all about DRY.

As in, if you want to modify anything, you should be able to modify it from one single place. If you need anything available across multiple files, consider defining its value in a `_vars` file and including it everywhere you need it. Also note this has nothing to do with code shortness, but with code maintainability and flexibility.
In fact, even if you do get to write more code (which, in practice, doesn't happen), the advantage of DRY far outweighs it.
Here's how it should be done:

```css
/* _vars.scss: */
$block:block;

/* a.scss: */
@import _vars;
.#{$block} {
  ...
}

/* b.scss: */
@import _vars;
.#{$block}__element {
  ...
}
```

Now, whenever you need to change `block` value, you can do it from one place: `_vars.scss`.

But, in practice, most people use the initial technique (nesting):

```css
.block {
  ...
  &__element {
    ...
  }
}
```

Chances are `.block` and `.block__element` are related and, overall, it makes more sense to put them in same file. As your app grows in complexity, you'll find it harder to keep track of your code if you over-complicate it.